# Moving a picture with the mouse is off centered

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I have a picture displayed but when I try to move it with my mouse my mouse is off centered from the image. Basically, when my mouse is in the center of the application screen, the image is in the top right of the screen. Another way to explain it is the mouse isn't directly over the image when I move it, its off to the side.

Below is the main code for it.

```
public class SlingshotSteve implements ApplicationListener{

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture;
private Sprite sprite;


@Override
public void create() { 
camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);     

batch = new SpriteBatch();


texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
sprite = new Sprite(texture);

sprite = new Sprite(texture);
sprite.setOrigin(0,0);
sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2,-sprite.getHeight()/2);


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
batch.dispose();
texture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {  
// Make the background color Black
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Mouse imput        
if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
    sprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX() - sprite.getWidth()/2,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() - sprite.getHeight()/2);
}
if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.RIGHT)){
    sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 -sprite.getWidth()/2, 
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);
}

batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
}
```

I think its a problem with the orthographic camera but I'm not sure, and even if I did know I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you probably forgot to unproject your coords.

```
Vector3 tmp=new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
camera.unproject(tmp);
float x=tmp.x,y=tmp.y;
```

And now use x and y as you want

```
if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
sprite.setPosition(x - sprite.getWidth()/2,
       y - sprite.getHeight()/2);
```

}

And remove sprite.setOrigin(0,0);  you don't need it.

Comment: How do I use the X and Y? What should I put?

Comment: When you say use the x and y as you want, how do i exactly use it? Sorry, I'm new at this.

Comment: X and y are now the world positions of your sprite. You converted your screen coords to world coords. X and Y are the position of the mouse on your screen